# Deleted local files automatically remove from git repo?

Tags: git

When I delete files in my local working directory and make a `git add .` `git commit` and finally `git push` the files are just in the remote repo and in the working directories of other people pulling my commit.

Is there a way besides `git rm` for every single file, to tell git to delete those files everywhere (remote repo and in the working directories of the others)?

Comment: Who do you think you are, trying to delete stuff in other people's own private local repos? `:p`

Comment: It is a repo from a publishing company and we are working on the same basis. So when one file isn't necessary anymore, we wish to delete it for everyone.

Comment: When you ran `git commit`, and you were in the editor typing your commit message, did you see any message about changes not staged for commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-u` option to `git add` to stage removal of deleted files.

```
git add -u
```

From the manpage:

> --update
>
> Only match `<filepattern>` against already tracked files in the index rather than the working tree. That means that it will never stage new files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files and that **it will remove files from the index if the corresponding files in the working tree have been removed**.
>
> If no `<filepattern>` is given, default to "."; in other words, update all tracked files in the current directory and its subdirectories.

As @farzad describes, if you then commit and push, then anyone pulling the latest version of the branch will see the relevant files deleted.

Comment: My solution is just a convoluted alternative to `git add -u`. Deleting now.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Both worked. Just to conserve the solution which worked also from Jubobs: `git rm \`git ls-files --deleted\``

Answer (score 2):

If the files are under version control by git (not in the excluded list), then you'd better use proper git command to remove the files:

```
 git rm filename
 git commit -m "removed filename because of the reason"
 git push
```

This will remove the file from version control, so after this anyone that pulls will have that file removed.

Comment: Lets assume that I have deleted several files in different folders or simply there are too many deleted files to remember. Is there a way to let git them find and make a `git rm` on all of them?